# Grouping data with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

I was given some data by an engineer and she is wondering if I could summarize her data so that it is on fewer rows if not on one row. A github link to some of the data is shown below and as you can see it is full of redundancy and null values. I have tried a simple grouping but that didn't work. I am now creating multiple views with each view adding a column. Within the creation each view I state that each column is not null, so that I can try to reduce the null rows. However I am still getting redundant sample ID's and column values are where they should not be because of that redundancy. Here is what I am doing for one of the views:

```
create or replace view leslie_6 as
select distinct s.SMPL_ID,s.EFFECTIVENESS_PNS_SCORE_,
s.PNS_BLANK,s.pns_nacl,
s.settable_solids,
t.perc_pass_10m
from leslie_5 s right join leslietable t on s.SMPL_ID = t.smpl_id
where s.EFFECTIVENESS_PNS_SCORE_ is not null and
s.PNS_BLANK is not null and 
s.pns_nacl is not null and
s.settable_solids is not null and 
t.perc_pass_10m is not null
group by s.SMPL_ID,s.EFFECTIVENESS_PNS_SCORE_,s.PNS_BLANK,
s.pns_nacl,s.settable_solids,t.perc_pass_10m
order by s.SMPL_ID
```

Another problem is that the sample ID is the closest thing I have to a key. I was hoping I could break down the data well enough so that the sampleID could be the key, but that's not really working. The table is over 7500 rows long and its a mess.

Here is a sample of the data I posted to GitHub. If you scroll to the bottom of the data you can get a horizontal scroll bar.

https://github.com/thomasawolff/verification_text_data/blob/master/Lydia%20query%20deicers%2020161005_sample.csv

Comment: You are using both distinct and group by - one or other is irrelevant. Sounds like what you need to do is lose the distinct, remove all but the s.smpl_id column from the group by and add `MAX()` around every column except s.smpl_id, assuming that across each smpl_id there is only at most 1 value present in a column. Those results look very much like the half-way point of a pre-11g style pivot query (by which I mean, where the columns are missing the aggregate function to collapse them into one row)!

Comment: Ok so would MAX() state that there can only be so many of each column?

Comment: `MAX()` would simply return the greatest value within that column across the group. If you have more than one value in a column, what do you want to be displayed in that column for the specific smpl_id?

Comment: Actually, given that set of input data over on github, what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Ok yes max() would work well for columns that are otherwise empty per sampleID. But if there are more than one entry per ID, and there are some, I would like both. So maybe min() and max() but not null?

Comment: What do I want the output to look like? Im still kind of figuring that out. But max() did a pretty good job of simplifying the data, but again the multiple values per ID

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to need to use COUNT() in combination with your GROUP BY statement but as above, the desired output would be useful to have.

Comment: The desired output is as much data as possible on one line per sampleID

Comment: Would a subquery in the select statement work in this case?

Comment: The table you posted has many 100% null ROWS - those can surely be deleted first. They serve no purpose. Then: I don't believe aggregate functions will work well on (most of) the columns, since they appear to be character strings, not numbers. (Obviously so with a value of <0.004.) It is really not clear how such "values" in a given column can be summarized; perhaps there are "normal" and "abnormal" ranges and occurrences of each must be counted? This is really a question for your engineer friend, you shouldn't have to come up with HOW to summarize the data.

Comment: Yes I agree. I am still trying to figure out the desired output and get an idea of just how this data could be broken down. Well thanks for the input I appreciate your time. Ill just keep slowly working on those things. Yes the string values in many of those columns make aggregate functions worthless but I can start by deleting the empty rows.

Comment: @hollow_Victory not if you have multiple values returned. If you can't actually tell us what you want the results to look like, there's not much we're going to be able to do to help you - we aren't there, we don't know your data, your tables, your requirements. We can guess, but it'd be pot luck as to whether we'd be right or not. I suggest you and/or your engineer spend some time deciding what the output should look like, based on the input data you already provided - then we stand a better chance of being able to help!

Comment: @hollow_Victory string values may be able to be aggregated together in a delimited list - it all depends on what needs to be displayed. Good luck in sorting that, and hopefully we'll be able to help you further once you have that logic in place *{:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query I ended up using to solve this problem. Using max() on all the columns worked very well. I then subtracted the test ID's having more than one value entry per column and what was left was correct. I didn't think using max() would have worked on any of the values that were not numeric. It did work probably because those values are worth more than the empty cells.

But I could have used something like:

```
select max(to_number(regexp_substr())
```

and I may do that just in case this needs to be done again. I had to focus so much on removing the double entries since they messed up the max() output for those test ID's

```
---*** Takes the max or the value of the only entry in a column
create or replace view maxdataset as
select t.smpl_id,
t.matl_cd,t.geog_area_t,
max(t.assay) as assay,
max(t.effectiveness_pns_score_) as effectiveness_pns_score,
max(t.pns_blank) as pns_blank,
max(t.pns_nacl) as pns_nacl,
max(t.settable_solids) as settable_solids,
max(t.perc_pass_10m) as perc_pass_10m,
max(t.ph) as ph,
max(t.as_) as as_,
max(t.ba) as ba,
max(t.cd) as cd,
max(t.cr) as cr,
max(t.cu) as cu,
max(t.pb) as pb,
max(t.hg) as hg,
max(t.se) as se,
max(t.zn) as zn,
max(t.cn) as cn,
max(t.p) as p,
max(t.s) as s,
max(t.sulfate) as sulfate,
max(t.phosphate) as phosphate,
max(t.k) as k,
max(t.ca) as ca,
min(t.mg) as mg,
max(t.nitrite) as nitrite,
max(t.nitrate) as nitrate,
max(t.chloride) as chloride
from leslietable t
group by t.smpl_id,t.matl_cd,t.geog_area_t
;
---*** Removes just test ID rows with columns having more than one entry per test ID
create or replace view doubleEffect_short as
select t.smpl_id
from LESLIETABLE t inner join LESLIETABLE s
on t.smpl_id = s.smpl_id where 
(t.effectiveness_pns_score_ <> s.effectiveness_pns_score_) or 
(t.pns_blank <> s.pns_blank) or (t.pns_nacl <> s.pns_nacl) or
(t.settable_solids <> s.settable_solids) or
(t.perc_pass_10m <> s.perc_pass_10m) or
(t.ph <> s.ph) or (t.as_ <> s.as_) or
(t.as_ <> s.as_) or (t.ba <> s.ba) or
(t.cd <> s.cd) or (t.cr <> s.cr) or
(t.cu <> s.cu) or (t.pb <> s.pb) or
(t.hg <> s.hg) or (t.se <> s.se) or
(t.zn <> s.zn) or (t.cn <> s.cn) or
(t.p <> s.p) or (t.sulfate <> s.sulfate) or
(t.phosphate <> s.phosphate) or
(t.k <> s.k) or (t.ca <> s.ca) or
(t.mg <> s.mg) or (t.nitrite <> s.nitrite) or
(t.nitrate <> s.nitrate) or (t.chloride <> s.chloride)
group by t.smpl_id
order by t.smpl_id
;
---*** Outputs all columns from max data set having more than one value per column
create or replace view final_data_sifter as
select  t.smpl_id,t.matl_cd,t.geog_area_t,t.assay,t.effectiveness_pns_score,
t.pns_blank,t.pns_nacl,t.settable_solids,t.perc_pass_10m,t.ph,t.as_,t.ba,t.cd,
t.cr,t.cu,t.pb,t.hg,t.se,t.zn,t.cn,t.p,t.s,t.sulfate,t.phosphate,t.k,t.ca,t.mg,
t.nitrite,t.nitrate,t.chloride 
from maxdataset t join doubleeffect_short s
on t.smpl_id = s.smpl_id
;
---*** Sutracts rows with multiple values per column from max data set 
create or replace view finalDataset_incomplete as
select * from maxdataset t
minus
select * from final_data_sifter
```